# BigQuery Table a Pub Sub Topic not working in Apache Beam Python SDK? Static source to Streaming Sink

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

**My basic requirement was to create a pipeline to read from BigQuery Table and then convert it into JSON and pass it onto a PubSub topic.**

---

At first I read from Big Query and tried to write it into Pub Sub Topic but got an `exception error saying "Pub Sub" is not supported for batch pipelines`. So I tried some workarounds and

I was able to work around this in python by

- Reading from BigQuery-> ConvertTo JSON string-> Save as text file in cloud storage (Beam pipeline)

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

json_string_output =   (
                          p
                          | 'Read from BQ' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                                query='SELECT * FROM '\
                                 '`project.dataset.table_name`',
                                 use_standard_sql=True)
                          | 'convert to json' >> beam.Map(lambda record: json.dumps(record))
                          | 'Write results' >> beam.io.WriteToText(outputs_prefix)
                      )

p.run()
```

- And then from there run a normal python script to read it line from file and pass it onto PubSub Topic

```
 # create publisher
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

    with open(input_file, 'rb') as ifp:
        header = ifp.readline()  
        # loop over each record
        for line in ifp:
            event_data = line   # entire line of input file is the message
            print('Publishing {0} to {1}'.format(event_data, pubsub_topic))
            publisher.publish(pubsub_topic, event_data)
```

[Python working codes repo](https://github.com/IamSaransh/BigqueryToGCSText--ThentoPubSub)

I'm not able to find a way to integrate both scripts within a single ApacheBeam Pipeline.

Comment: You can use WriteToPubsub. Details here -->https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#text-files-on-cloud-storage-to-pubsub-stream

OR You can use templates if you have data in GCS and you want to stream it to Pubsub-topic.  Details here -->https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#text-files-on-cloud-storage-to-pubsub-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your pipeline does not have any unbounded PCollections, it will be automatically run in batch mode. You can force a pipeline to run in streaming mode with the `--streaming` command line flag.

Comment: Was just starting with dataflow when I posted this question. Turns out the use case we had, had some limitations using the python SDK. I have recreated the same using java. Appreciate the answer.